# Validating single Property in model which is binded customly

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to simply validate a single property of that model

```
public ActionResult Rate([Bind(Exclude="Score")]RatingModel model)
{    
    if(ModelState.IsValid)
    {
         //here model is validated without check Score property validations
         model.Score = ParseScore( Request.Form("score")); 
         // Now i have updated Score property manualy and now i want to validate Score property    
    }
}
```

after assign Score manually, Mvc framework does not check validation on model. Now i want to validate Score property with all validation attributes which currently exist on model. 
    // How to do that easily ? Mvc Framework support this scenario ?

Here is my model

```
public class RatingModel
{
    [Range(0,5),Required]
    public int Score { get; set; }  
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found right solution. I simply call TryValidateModel and it validate properties include Score property.

```
public ActionResult Rate([Bind(Exclude="Score")]RatingModel model)
{    
    model.Score = ParseScore( Request.Form("score"));
    if(TryValidateModel(model))
    {
        ///validated with all validations
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using MVC3. Any particular reason why you aren't setting some of the most basic validation rules in the Model?

You can set some validation rules directly in the model. For example, if you want to validate an email field, you can set the rules and even the error messages in the model itself.

```
[Required(ErrorMessage = "You must type in something in the field.")]
[RegularExpression(".+\\@.+\\..+", ErrorMessage = "You must type in a valid email address.")]
[Display(Name = "Email:")]
public string Email { get; set; }
```

Read more here:
http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs

Comment: Hey you missunderstood me. I am aware of what you said.Please check updated version of question. If i have a reason to bind Score property manually How i can get benefit of ModelState.Valid check ? I want to able to do it in easy way without reading attributes and add errors to ModelState.AddModelError method

Answer (score 0):

You need to check if the ModelState is valid in the Controller Action:

```
public ActionResult Action(RatingModel viewModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid) 
    {
        //Model is validated
    }
    else
    {
        return View(viewModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Marting - I have reupdate my question for make it more clear. Can you check reagain ?

Comment: You are excluding Score when you model bind ... why don't you just include it, and it will validate for you?

Comment: MVC can not bind that property that is why i am binding it custom way. If i include it so ModelState.IsValid would be false always. Thats why it is excluded.